# Alternatives to Rudin

Tags: analysis

I'm taking an advanced calculus class this semester and we've been using Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis. I was wondering if anyone could suggest some good analysis textbooks aimed toward undergrad students that I can use as a supplement.

Comment: Abbott's Understanding Analysis.

Comment: See [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639950/exercise-book-for-elementary-introduction-to-real-analysis).

Comment: You might want to read this too. All the books mentioned are great supplements to Rudin. And like I've mentioned there my favourite is Bartle. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703685/what-are-the-pre-requisites-required-to-learn-real-analysis/703704#703704

Comment: A good book that's a little more gentle / introductory than Rudin (and similar books) is [Fundamental Ideas of Analysis](http://www.amazon.com/Fundamental-Ideas-Analysis-Michael-Reed/dp/0471159964) by Reed.

Answer (score 1):

the way of analysis by Robert S. Strichartz

[http://www.amazon.com/Analysis-Revised-Edition-Bartlett-Mathematics/dp/0763714976/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1398408228&sr=8-1&keywords=the+way+of+analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0763714976)