# Understanding Analysis by Abott (Prerequisites)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, intuition

I just bought „Understanding Analysis“ by Stephan Abott.

I am a CS Student who already passed his math lectures in Germany but I want a better understanding since I memorized a lot.
I want to build a deep understanding and intuition.

My goal is to self study math.

„Understanding Analysis“ is a introduction to rigerous analysis, so basically proof based calculus right?

So would a calculus book before working through „Understanding Analysis“ beneficial to get an intuition?
Or does „Understanding Analysis“ cover the same stuff as an Calculus book?

Comment: Abbot develops everything from scratch, but it will be easier to understand if you already understand calculus at an intuitive level. I’d say dive into Abbot and backtrack to fill in gaps in knowledge as necessary.

Comment: you dont need any prerequisitesmore than a course on calculus. I started learning math from the excellent book of Stephen Abbott, some years ago. The book of Abbott is an introduction to what is called real analysis. Enjoy the lecture.

Comment: @littleO could you maybe recommend some books to get better on calculus on an intuitive level? Would Spivak be a good choice or somewhat unnecessary when I already got Abbotts book?

Comment: Calculus by Spivak is a great book, but it also develops calculus rigorously and is in fact an introduction to real analysis. You could maybe try Spivak's Hitchhiker's Guide to Calculus or Strang's Calculus textbook.

Comment: From CS you will hopefully eventually become familiar with the basics of formal mathematics, e.g., sets, relations, functions, proof techniques. If you aren't comfortable with these I'd recommend looking up Velleman's *How to Prove It*, which is very accessible.

Comment: @DavidKraemer sure I am already familiar with these, but to be honest I learned a lot just to pass and not to understand. But now I found my passion for math. 
I already got the book: "How to prove it" two weeks ago and I am working through it!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the pre- requisites required to learn Real Analysis?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703685/what-are-the-pre-requisites-required-to-learn-real-analysis)